# Function to get the shape of bottom of a bottle

Tags: functions

I wanted to plot the following function [the shape of a bottom of a wine bottle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4lKj.png)

Can I get the function form?

Comment: Looks like maybe it goes from parabola to quartic and back to parabola. Or just quartic.

Comment: Maybe something like this $$3x^4+5x^3+x^2-x+3y^4+5y^3+y^2-y=z$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-1)^2.
\end{align}
Here's the [wolframalpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2-1)%5E2).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a bottle, it's a surface of revolution. So, you really only need to figure out the shape of its cross-section. So, invent a curve $z = f(x)$ that looks like the right cross-section to you. Then the surface equation is $z = f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$.